# Reformatting C# code, breaking lines af opetator plus

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following code and I would like to have the data for the text boxes to be displayed on different lines. How would I go about this?

Here's the code:

```
m.Body = name.Text + phone.Text + email.Text;
```

Comment: win forms or web form you using?

Comment: Web forms i have it now working with Environment.newline

Comment: @PhelimBrady if you got it to work, then please accept the answer which you learn from. There's an outline of a check mark to the left of each answer whcih you can click.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to set the `TextMode` of the textbox control to `TextBoxMode.MultiLine`, and then add an `Environment.NewLine` between the elements: format strings can be handy here:

```
string body = string.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}", Environment.NewLine, 
      name.text, phone.text, email.text);
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the multiline property of the textbox to true and add newline characters to your string. For example (using the join method):

```
var items = new string[] { name.Text, phone.Text, email.Text };
var myString = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, items);
```

Or using the format() method:

```
string myString = String.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}", Environment.NewLine, name.text, phone.text, email.text);
```

You can also use the stringbuilder approach:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(name.Text);
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
sb.Append(phone.Text);
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
sb.Append(email.Text);

var myString = sb.ToString();
```

Or just use the AppendLine() method:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(name.Text);
sb.AppendLine(phone.Text);
sb.AppendLine(email.Text);

var myString = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: ...or you can use `sb.AppendLine` instead, and skip the sb.Append(Environment.NewLine)` lines.